# how to automatically add a schedule from Google Sheets into Calendar?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-sheets-api

I have tried to implement this code to integrate google calendar with my spreadsheet, but i am fail until now. Follow the code...

```
function scheduleShifts() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("Dados!CJ3").getValue();
    var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("Dados!CI5:CK3500").getValues();
for (x=0; x<signups.length;x++)
{
    var shift = signups[x];
    var startTime = shift[0];
    var endTime = shift[1];
    var volunteer= shift[2];
    eventCal.createEvent(volunteer,startTime,endTime);
}
}
```

Error message:

21:19:29    Erro    Exception: The parameters (String,String,String) don't match the method signature for CalendarApp.Calendar.createEvent. scheduleShifts  @ Agenda.gs:12

Based article:

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/g-suite-pro-tip-how-to-automatically-add-a-schedule-from-google-sheets-into-calendar

Can you help me?

Comment: I think that in your script, the arguments `a,b,c` of `createEvent(a, b, c)` are string, date object, and date object. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#createEvent(String,Date,Date)) From your showing error, it seems that all values are string. I think that the reason for your issue is due to this. So, if you want to directly retrieve date object from Spreadsheet, can you confirm Spreadsheet, again. Or, if you want to convert date string on Spreadsheet to date object using script, I think that it is required to know your actual value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function scheduleShifts() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("Dados!CJ3").getValue();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("Dados!CI5:CK3500").getValues();
  for (x=0; x<signups.length;x++) {
    var shift = signups[x];
    var startTime = new Date(shift[0]);
    var endTime = new Date(shift[1]);
    var volunteer= shift[2];
    eventCal.createEvent(volunteer,startTime,endTime);
  }
}
```

Comment: At now, i have an issue with implantation of the project... i will wait a time and try again.

Comment: I don't understand you last comment

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

Comment: I think i need use Utilities.sleep()... how many milliseconds should i use? And where???

Comment: Try 60 milliseconds.  Somewhere in the loop

Comment: Exception: You have been creating or deleting too many calendars or calendar events in a short time. Please try again later.

Comment: I have the same error with Utilities.sleep(60)

Comment: Can i create only new events that i add in the spreadsheet? At now, if i run two times the script, a duplicate event is generated. I think i will need a conditional to select only new records in the spreadsheet. Please, help me!

Answer (score 0):

The method signature for [calendar#createEvent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createEvent(String,Date,Date)) is

[image]

You are currently sending string parms (String,String,String). As shown in the error message

> Exception: The parameters **(String,String,String)** don't match the method signature for CalendarApp.Calendar.createEvent. scheduleShifts

While the method requires that both the start date and end date are actually dates not strings.

```
var event = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createEvent('Apollo 11 Landing',
    new Date('July 20, 1969 20:00:00 UTC'),
    new Date('July 21, 1969 21:00:00 UTC'));
Logger.log('Event ID: ' + event.getId());
```